# Search question and answer Hyperlinks for a hostname?

Tags: support, search, hyperlinks

Recently the URL `www.antlr.org` was changed from pointing to `www.antlr3.org` to `www.antlr4.org`. Needless to say there are links that use `www.antlr.org` for referring to `www.antlr3.org` that are now wrong.

While I know that search with `www.antlr.org` will find if `www.antlr.org` is in the text, it will not find it in the hyperlinks. How do I search the hyperlinks?

Comment: search for `url:*.anltr.org` I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a URL search operator present. Something like this should work well:

```
url:"*antlr.org*"
```

[See the results.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*antlr.org*%22)

Note the need for an asterisk before *and* after.Otherwise it will only returns links directly to antlr.org with no path after it.